# How to search array of keywords inside of a collection in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to search a single keyword inside of a collection in firebase flutterl. ButI want to know how to search an array of the keyword inside of collection in firebase using flutter???

please help me...

Comment: Do you need to check if a particular keyword exists in an array in Firestore?

Comment: no this is not what i mean

Comment: I want to search array of keyword inside of a collection in firebase

Answer (score 1):

I found this function:

```
var ref = _firestore
           .collection("collection1")
           .where("att", arrayContains: array);
```

This will return all the documents in `collection1` collection where the array `att` contain either of the items in the `array` you pass. Then you can filter through that array and check which documents' `att` array contains all those items.